# pyspark timestamp with timezone

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract out a value from a table using pyspark and I need the value in this format: 2020-06-17T15:08:24z

```
df = spark.sql('select max(lastModDt)as lastModDate from db.tbl')

jobMetadata = existingMaxModifiedDate.withColumn("maxDate", date_format(to_timestamp(existingMaxModifiedDate.lastModDate, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS"), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS"))
```

However, I keep getting null for created column "maxDate". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful -

```scala
  val timeDF = spark.sql(
      """
        |select current_timestamp() as time1,
        | translate(date_format(current_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ') ,' ', 'T') as time2,
        | translate(date_format(current_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd#HH:mm:ss$') ,'#$', 'Tz') as time3
      """.stripMargin)
    timeDF.show(false)
    timeDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
      * |time1                  |time2                   |time3               |
      * +-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
      * |2020-06-30 21:22:04.541|2020-06-30T21:22:04+0530|2020-06-30T21:22:04z|
      * +-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- time1: timestamp (nullable = false)
      * |-- time2: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- time3: string (nullable = false) 
      */
```

Comment: Thanks. This returns a string and still doesn't add the Z that I need at the end. Here's what I got when I ran it '2020-06-30T15:18:41+0000'

Comment: use `time3`, also please note that `date_format` always return string type

Comment: Is this doable in python instead of scala and also with datetime type instead of string? Thank you.

Comment: You can use this in python as is inside spark.sql(). I think, date_format converts timestamp to string type using provided format.